# How to show default value in console in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In that Project I have a form, In that form I have two Input

Tags. For first input tag I defined the value, For the second input tag I am assigning value by

using state. Now I am trying to console values of two Input tags but I am getting only second

Input tag value. So someone please help me to get Two Input tag values from form

This is Form.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './aum-company-modal.css';
import Aumservice from '../../service/aum-service';
import { Button, Col, Modal, ModalBody,ModalFooter, ModalHeader, Row, FormGroup, Label, Input, } from 'reactstrap';

const AumCompanyModal = (props) => {

    const [data, sendData] = useState({})


    const [firstInputValue] = useState('1000')
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');


    const handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const { name, value } = target;
        console.warn(name,value)
const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value })
        sendData(newData)
        if (value > -1 && value < 100000000000000000000000000000000000) {
            setInputValue(value);
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(data)
    }


    return (
        <Row>
            <Col md="6" sm="6" xs="6">

                <Modal isOpen={props.openModal}
                >
                    <ModalHeader >Add new</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <Row>
                            <Col md="12" sm="12" xs="12">
                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Label for="exampleName">Min Value</Label>
                                    <Input
                                        type="text"
                                        name="minValue"
                                        placeholder="Enter minimum value"
                                        value={firstInputValue}
                                    />
                                </FormGroup>
                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Label for="exampleName">Max Value</Label>
                                    <Input
                                        type="number"
                                        name="maxValue"
                                        placeholder="Enter maximum value"
                                        min='1000' max='100000000000000000000000000000000000'
                                        value={inputValue}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                    />
                                </FormGroup>
                            </Col>

                        </Row>


                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={props.closeModal}>
                            Cancel
                </Button>
                        <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} color="primary">
                            Submit
                </Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
}

export default AumCompanyModal
```

If you have any doubt please put a comment.

Comment: if your 1st value is not being controlled by state, how you will get that from state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason, you need to hard code some value, use state variable as value and then you will have that variable in `handleSubmit`. Or you can use `ref` and get value from that ref

```
const [firstValue] = useState('100');
<Input
   type="text"
   name="minValue"
   placeholder="Enter minimum value"
   value={firstValue}
/>
```

Or you can use `React.useRef()`

```
const firstInput = React.useRef();

<Input
   type="text"
   name="minValue"
   placeholder="Enter minimum value"
   value="1000"
   ref={firstInput}
/>
// in handleSubmit
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(firstInput.current.value)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Zohaib Ijaz, I Edited my code Now If I am trying to console two input tags, but I am getting only second Input tag in console please help me to solve this.

Comment: It's because you have never set the 1st field in `data`. You are replacing `data` value ({}) with 2nd input value in handleChange callback so it will not get 1st field value automatically. What do you want to do exactly

Comment: I want to send data to backend, that data is first input tag and a second input tag, this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Cruse you can access both values in `handleSubmit`. you can create object/array whatever you want to be sent to backend e.g. `const payload  = { first: firstInputValue, second: inputValue }`